# "Coud not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SqlClient, Version=4.6.1.6" Error al abrir aplicación creada

Tags: visual-studio, exe, nuget

Tengo una aplicación que entre las librerías que usa está la de System.Data.Sql.Client, al crear el instalador en Microsoft Installer Project la versión dice que es la 4.6.1.5, pero en la carpeta donde se encuentra el .dll del Sql.Client la versión es diferente, ya lo instale y desinstale en el Nuget y ya limpie y compile la solución, pero la versión nunca coincide, hay alguna manera de hacer que la versión coincida o que funcione a pesar de que no coincida?
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]